# How can I develop a 264 "codec format worked in VideoView API?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I have got a big problem. I have a video "tc10.264" I downloaded from live555.com. I can not play the video that using videoview,exoplayer and vitamio sdk
on android.
I know that the video is codec.it is not container like mp4,flv etc.
Later, I played the video with "ffplay -f  h264 tc10.264 " via on windows console.
and ffmpeg shows me this spec. 
h264(baseline), yubj420p and 25 fps.

Okay this video is exist. 
After, I downloaded ffmpeg from on ubuntu in virtual machine. And I build(compile) the ffmpeg with x264 it as shown below.

my directory path is like ffmpeg > x264 and I compiled libx264.a for ffmpeg from x264 folder.

**Note:** my android phone has architecturally armeabi_v7a

There is build_android_arm.sh script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo starting building .... 
NDK=/home/lscodex/android-sdk/ndk-bundle
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
PREFIX=./android/arm

function build_one
{
  ./configure \
  --prefix=$PREFIX \
  --enable-static \
  --enable-pic \
  --host=arm-linux \
  --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
  --sysroot=$PLATFORM

  make clean
  make
  make install
}

build_one

echo Android ARM builds finished....
```

After, I have a folder called android containing lib,include and bin files.So, I compiled script that shown below to achieve shared folder (".so") in ffmpeg folder.
there is build_android_armeabi_v7a.sh script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Android starting armeabi_v7a
NDK=/home/lscodex/android-sdk/ndk-bundle
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
CPU=armeabi_v7a
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU

GENERAL="\
--enable-small \
--enable-cross-compile \
--extra-libs="-lgcc" \
--arch=arm \
--cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
--cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
--extra-cflags="-I../x264/android/arm/include" \
--extra-ldflags="-L../x264/android/arm/lib" "


MODULES="\
--enable-gpl \
--enable-libx264"

H264TEST="\
--enable-encoder=libx264 \
--enable-encoder=libx264rgb \
--enable-decoder=h264 \
--enable-muxer=h264 \
--enable-demuxer=h264 \
--enable-parser=h264"

function build_ARMv7
{
  ./configure \
  --target-os=android \
  --prefix=$PREFIX \
  ${GENERAL} \
  --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
  --enable-shared \
  ${H264TEST} \
  --disable-static \
  --extra-cflags="-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -funswitch-loops -finline-limit=300" \
  --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog" \
  --enable-zlib \
  ${MODULES} \
  --disable-doc \
  --enable-neon

  make clean
  make
  make install
}


build_ARMv7
echo Android ARMv7-a builds finished
```

finally, I obtained another an android folder that contain shared library. 
I integrated the files from the android studio. I created CMakeLists.txt and cpp folder.
So, Everything is perfectly working, I think. 
this ndk code helping me for receive a duration of bugs_bunny.mp4 video.

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_lscodex_just_videoplayertesting2_VideoProcessing_videoDuration(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject obj,
        jstring input) {


    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;

     if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx,convertStringFileToChar(env,input),NULL,NULL)<0){
         throwException(env,"Could not open input file ");
         loge("Could not open input file ");
         return 0;
     }
     if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx,NULL)<0){
         throwException(env,"Failed to retrieve input stream information");
         loge("Failed to retrieve input stream information");
         return 0;
     }

    logd("I reached it here :) ");


    int64_t duration = pFormatCtx->duration;
    avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);
    avformat_free_context(pFormatCtx);
    return (jint) (duration / AV_TIME_BASE);
}
```

at least for mp4 video format.
So, my question is, How can I run **tc10.264** codec video format via ffmpeg on exoplayer or on videoview api?

Comment: Have you tried to decode it with MediaCodec?

Comment: Actually, I tried mediaCodec with mediaPlayer but I did not just try it to decoding.I am gonna look at it. @szatmary

Comment: @szatmary , hey, I tried for tc10.264 video format in mediaCodec for decoding but mediaExtractor always gives an error that Failed to instantiate extractor.

Comment: Check output of you ffmpeg build. I bet that you don't have libx264 & your ffmpeg just ignores your `x264` flags

Comment: @DmitriiZ. hello, I have got files that libx264.so and x264.h, x264_config.h. and I checked output of ffmpeg build and I didn't see any error. Also I integrated these files to android project.However, there is something I do not understand that, how do I add videoview api after converts ".264" video codec to mp4 for playback?